# Use couchDB with vert.x

Tags: java, couchdb, couchbase, vert.x

I'm looking into a NoSQL database for use with Vert.x
Based on the not so favorable results mongoDB is out, so I'm looking at CouchDB/CouchBase, not at least since some of our data collection runs on RaberryPI fed by Arduino I/O (with a Rasbery PI CouchDB instance for offline collection).

What Java library would be suitable/best for use with CouchDB and Vert.x

Comment: Just to be sure you know it, Couchbase and Couchdb are 2 different products http://www.couchbase.com/couchbase-vs-couchdb . If you want to use it with Couchbase you can use the Java client - http://www.couchbase.com/develop/java/current

Comment: I know. Java support quality will be one of the deciding factors. We do have CouchDB running on Raspberry PI for data collection but need to make a decision for the central system. CouchDB can replicate with Couchbase with the gateway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know a lot about vert.x but it appears to run on the JVM, so you should just be able to use [Ektorp](https://github.com/helun/Ektorp), which is pretty much the standard Java library for CouchDB nowadays. It covers all the core functionality, it's fairly well thought out, and the maintainer has been reasonably responsive to pull requests etc, as far as I've seen.

There's more documentation on Ektorp [here](http://www.ektorp.org/).

Comment: Note that this only works with Couchdb, for Couchbase you need this library http://www.couchbase.com/develop/java/current